# Compress folder with files rar/zip on android

Tags: android, file, encryption, zip, android-external-storage

I've faced one problem. I want to store a certain folder with media data here `/data/data/com.package.name` using `Context.getExternalFilesDirs`. But i want to hide the data from users. But everyone can get this files from `/data/data/com.package.name` folder. Even if the files are hidden, still people with rooted devices can access this data. So i need some way to `encrypt` or zip the folder to protect it. How can i protect the folder?
Can i use Zip with password? Is it safe?

I think it's not good practice to `encrypt` all binary files and `decrypt` them because it will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent user from accessing these files. If user wants them he or she can extract password from your app and decrypt zip archive.

When passwords are on your server then files can't be decrypted, but when your app downloads password to decrypt data then user can sniff that password.
If you want to store data that no one should ever access (e.g. passwords) I'm afraid that you should read about [Security Through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

Basically when your application can decrypt data, advanced user can do it too.

For normal users (with non-rooted phone) storing files in `/data/data/` are not accessible. But with rooted phone there is no way to stop users from getting what they want.

Comment: how can he/she extract password from my app? i can store pass on server side

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Very nice java library http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/
does the work: here is an example

```
public void unzipFile(){
    String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String source = path+"/Download/circus.zip";
    String destination = path+"/Download/";
    String password = "1234567";

    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword(password);
        }
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But remember that it is not secure since you have password in app ;)
even if password is stored on remote server it doesn't prevent users from sniffing traffic :)

Comment: the main problem is that zip is easy to brootforce, not the password storage problem. I can use secret keys while exchanging data between server and good luck with finding the password, maybe in 100 years you'll find it.

Comment: But even then decompresses data will be stored somewhere ;)
ram can be easly dumped to file ;)
with rooted device everything is possible :)